# Davinci Resolve Image Disappear when transform/crop control is selected or clicked

Tags: video, transform, editing, resolve

It starts out fine, and the image is where it is supposed to be. When I click on the image anywhere it disappears, and I am left with ...

[image]
That defeat the purpose for transforming, cropping, etc.

Apparently this is not a new problem from my research trying to find a solution. 
But, I can't find any kind of solution, suggustions, or tips.

Any help would be very, very useful.

Comment: An update: I can kind of get it working by doing small adjustments while the timeline is selected, then click off the time line, then back on the time line to see the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Days after I posted this clip.

I was editing video and just clicked on transform by mistake and noticed.

[image]

I saw that anything that fell into the black area was visible.

When zoomed in and out the oval black area turned more square like. 
I looked through the menu and thought it had something to do with "Show Viewer Overlay". 
I  did the hot key for that :
     Hot Key - Shift + `
and suddenly it start working.

I tried to get it back to the point where it wasn't working again to try this out on it again, but I couldn't.

This is what worked for me and it may help someone else along the way.

Below is a picture of the working solution.

[image]

After visibly positioning the text(before I could position it, but I couldn't see it while I was positioning it. )

[image]

After all that I noticed that "Show Viewer Overlay" So, it more that likely was shift while working with it that did the trick. Since I could replicate the problem I do not know.

It was either shift or shift + ` that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my Resolve 16 the exact same problem was solved by enabling checkbox "**Show Timecode Overlays**" in the "..." menu in the upper bar at right.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/720lF.png)

Answer (score 0):

While struggling with the same problem and non of the solutions above worked... here is the fix I discovered...

While on edit/adjust mode, on the timeline, add a marker...
[image: add marker]

Then drag the time line out then back to the created marker...
[image: drag out and back to marker]

Done! You will notice, as mentioned by OP that the edit screen should be black. Also there is a marker name pop up at the top-left of it.

[image]